# Adding elements to an array in C#

Tags: c#

I am a newbie to programming c# and I want to add an element to an array.

Here's my function:

```
public bool AddPlayer(string PlayerName,string token)
{
    static int i = 0;  // <---- Error

    if ( PlayerIndex < MAX_NUMBER_OF_PLAYERS )
    {          
        Player[i]= PlayerName
        i++;
    }

    return true;
}
```

The static int i = 0 results in an error.  Is there another way to do this?

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like you don't really know how many players you are going to store (up to a maximum). In this case you should rather use a `List<string>` to store your player names, which will resize to fit any number of players:

```
private List<string> players = new List<string>();

public void AddPlayer(string playerName,string token)
{
   players.Add(playerName);
}
```

Comment: +1 for explaining, Using List. :), and +1 for make to 50 K :P :)

Comment: If you need it to be an array later on, List has a "ToArray" function which copies the contents into the correct size array. You'd probably be better off forgetting about arrays and keeping the List if you can.

Answer (score 1):

if you use List instead of an array....  (its far more likely a List will serve you better)

you can go `Player.Add(PlayerName);`

eg

```
var players = new List<string>();

players.Add("bob");
players.Add("mary);
```

but most likely you will want a player class, so you can add other interesting bits of information about "players".

```
class Player
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

then

```
var players = new List<Player>();

players.Add(new Player() { Name = "bob" });
players.Add(new Player() { Name = "mary" });
```

Answer (score 1):

The usual way to do this is to use a `List`, not an array.  However, assuming you can't do that, you should make the index a (non-static) member of the class and initialise it to 0 in the constructor.

Comment: Does anyone know why C# doesn't allow static variables in member functions?  You would think that it would be best to put the variables closest to the place that they are used.

Comment: @user1164199 It was probably expected to cause more confusion than anything else; I somewhat agree, the times when you really do need it (and you aren't better-off splitting the functionality into another class) aren't that common.  If you do need it, here's a possible implementation: http://whathecode.wordpress.com/2011/06/13/beyond-private-accessibility/

Comment: Please, do _not_ use that though. ;p (As is explained in the blog post.)

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to make `i` a static class member, not a local variable in the method.  You probably want to give it a more meaningful name, too.

Answer (score 0):

If you actually need a static variable then you need to define it *outside* of the method and within the class definition.

```
static int i = 0;

public bool AddPlayer(string playerName, string token)
{
    // method implementation here...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can change "i"  as Static class member, or you can change the function to a static method

```
public static bool AddPlayer(string PlayerName,string token)
```